# Convert n way contingency table to a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I am trying to create a table with the number of items sold by product name,  year and region. I want a table that looks like below. Is there a way to do this in R rather than writing a sql query using sqldf function?

```
Product_Name      Region     Year     Count
English Muffins        1     2015     10000
Bagel                  1     2015      5601
Croissants              ....................
```

Here is the code to generate sample data. This dummy data does not correspond to the sample counts above.

```
Product_Name <- c("English Muffins","croissants","Kaiser rolls","Bagels","cinnamon puff","strawberry pastry")
Region_ID <- c(1:6)
Transaction_year <- c(2011:2016)

x <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:6)
  {
  for (j in 1:6)
    { 
    for(k in 1:6)
      {
      x <- rbind(x, data.frame(Product = Product_Name[i], Region = Region_ID[j], Year = Transaction_year[k]))
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The base function `as.data.frame.table` will do this. I'm assuming you either have or can make an R contingency table along these lines:

```
mt <- with(x, table(Product,Region,Year))
```

You then get the desired "long format" object with:

```
 str(as.data.frame(mt))

'data.frame':   216 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Product: Factor w/ 6 levels "English Muffins",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 4 ...
 $ Region : Factor w/ 6 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Year   : Factor w/ 6 levels "2011","2012",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Freq   : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

The other useful table-flattening function is `ftable`. For a three way table it presents a more compact version of the display that `print.table` would yield :

```
ftable(mt)
                         Year 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016
Product           Region                                   
English Muffins   1              1    1    1    1    1    1
                  2              1    1    1    1    1    1
                  3              1    1    1    1    1    1
                  4              1    1    1    1    1    1
                  5              1    1    1    1    1    1
                  6              1    1    1    1    1    1
croissants        1              1    1    1    1    1    1
                  2              1    1    1    1    1    1
                  3              1    1    1    1    1    1
                  4              1    1    1    1    1    1
                  5              1    1    1    1    1    1
                  6              1    1    1    1    1    1
Kaiser rolls      1              1    1    1    1    1    1
                  2              1    1    1    1    1    1
                  3              1    1    1    1    1    1
#-----snipped output--------
```

On the other hand if the request is to replicate numbers of rows by the Count variable then it would be done thusly:

```
#Makes something like your original dataframe:
orig <- structure(list(Product_Name = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("Bagel", 
"English_Muffins"), class = "factor"), Region = c(1L, 1L), Year = c(2015L, 
2015L), Count = c(5L, 4L)), .Names = c("Product_Name", "Region", 
"Year", "Count"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

xlong <- orig[ rep(rownames(orig), orig$Count) , ]
    > xlong
       Product_Name Region Year Count
1   English_Muffins      1 2015     5
1.1 English_Muffins      1 2015     5
1.2 English_Muffins      1 2015     5
1.3 English_Muffins      1 2015     5
1.4 English_Muffins      1 2015     5
2             Bagel      1 2015     4
2.1           Bagel      1 2015     4
2.2           Bagel      1 2015     4
2.3           Bagel      1 2015     4
```

Comment: Thank You! The ftable function is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

```
Product_Name <- c("English Muffins","croissants","Kaiser rolls","Bagels","cinnamon puff","strawberry pastry")
Region_ID <- c(1:6)
Transaction_year <- c(2011:2016)

x <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:6)
{
  for (j in 1:6)
  { 
    for(k in 1:6)
    {
      x <- rbind(x, data.frame(Product = Product_Name[i], Region = Region_ID[j], Year = Transaction_year[k]))
    }
  }
}

x$count <- 1

xx <- aggregate(x[,"count"],by=list(x$Product,x$Year,x$Region),sum)
colnames(xx) <- c("Product", "Year", "Region", "Count")
head(xx)

            Product Year Region Count
1   English Muffins 2011      1     1
2        croissants 2011      1     1
3      Kaiser rolls 2011      1     1
4            Bagels 2011      1     1
5     cinnamon puff 2011      1     1
6 strawberry pastry 2011      1     1
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this by using `data.table` and a `by` statement. Very similar to a `SQL` group-by:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x)[,count := .N, by = c("Product","Region","Year") ]
head(x)

           Product Region Year count
1: English Muffins      1 2011     1
2: English Muffins      1 2012     1
3: English Muffins      1 2013     1
4: English Muffins      1 2014     1
5: English Muffins      1 2015     1
6: English Muffins      1 2016     1
```

Comment: Thank You! This was useful. I am wondering, how we could do this without adding the "count" variable to the original dataset.

Comment: @user3897 This suggests that all of us answer-ers have misunderstood your question. Are you trying to take the original dataframe and expand the number of rows so that each combination of factors has 'Counts" number of rows? (I'm quite sure this has been asked and answered before.)

Comment: @42- Your solution was the best. Since, as.data.frame(table(x)) returns 6*6*6=216 rows which is not very intutive.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need for complicated code here. All you need is one line of code:

```
> as.data.frame(table(x))
              Product Region Year Freq
1     English Muffins      1 2011    1
2          croissants      1 2011    1
3        Kaiser rolls      1 2011    1
4              Bagels      1 2011    1
5       cinnamon puff      1 2011    1
6   strawberry pastry      1 2011    1
...
```

The `table` function produces the contingency table as a 3-dimensional array, and `as.data.frame` converts the contingency table to a data frame in the format that you want. If `x` contains other columns, make sure to subset it to only the columns you want to tabulate.